# Windows Phone 7 Hiding the Application Bar

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to be able to press a button to disable the menu bar in my application. If you go

```
menubar.IsVisible = false;
```

it throws a null reference exception. The menu bar is declared in XAML.

Anyone know if its possible to hide it on the fly like this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access this as a static member on ApplicationBar. i.e.

```
ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true/false;
```

Some background here on why ApplicationBar doesn't play like normal silverlight elements.

[Why are the ApplicationBar objects not FrameworkElements? - Peter Torr's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ptorr/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Been searching for hours, this indeed is the case. You have to make a static reference to the applicationbar.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I found it. You can't call the name you've given it, have to use `applicationbar.isivisble = false`

Answer (score 1):

To do it in code behind if you have not referenced it other than in XAML:

```
(ApplicationBar as ApplicationBar).IsVisible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;