# WP7 - show hide application bar

Tags: windows-phone-7

In many of the Windows Phone 7 apps, the application bar is hidden by default and when you press and hold down on the screen, the application bar is made visible. As many of the WP7 apps have this behavior, I was wondering, if there was in-built support for this kind of behavior with the ApplicationBar and how do I go about using it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 Hiding the Application Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116311/windows-phone-7-hiding-the-application-bar)

Comment: Hi Rajah, not 100% sure the above is what youre trying to do, but check it out. You mentioned holding down an area of the screen to open the app bar. Not sure what you meant by that.. maybe you can clarify if the above doesn't help.

Comment: can you tell us one specific app that has this behavior?  I've never seen an application bar come and go based on a hold event.  I've seen Popups that do, but never the app bar.

Comment: @John the Kindle app does this. But on `Tap` not `Hold`.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like nonstandard UI behaviour. You should consider using the WP7 toolkit ContextMenu instead for contextual actions.

Comment: You guys are right, the tap and hold action only brings up a context menu and not the app-bar. This is not a duplicate though (Mick N) because I knew how to make the app-bar visible/invisible. I thought that the tap and hold allowed for automated visibility of App-bar - I was wrong!

Comment: since this isn't really a duplicate, and you validated that your own assumptions were wrong, you should either edit the question or add an answer and accept that so it doesn't stay open forever with an incorrect assumption in the question.

Comment: Actually, after some digging, I did find that the Microsoft developed Pictures Hub, does exactly what I am describing in my question. Go into Pictures Hub, select an Image and then "Press and Hold" - voila the AppBar menu shows up. Based on that Matt Lacey's answer is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the GestureService in the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) to detect the `Hold` event.

For example.
If you had this xaml on a page:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="lorem ipsum ...">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="TapAndHold" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</TextBlock>
```

and the following for the event handler:

```
private void TapAndHold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = !this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible;
}
```

then holding down any where on the textblock would toggle the display of the ApplicationBar.

If you wanted the toggling if the user tapped and held anywhere on the page then you could attach the gesture listener to the root object of the page. e.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Hold="TapAndHold" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ApplicationBar property of the current page and toggle the IsVisible property accordingly to show/hide the ApplicationBar. The ApplicationBar is handled by the operating system, so the animation for showing and hiding it will be handled for you.