# How can I long press ApplicationBarIconButton in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I want to long press ApplicationBarIconButton in wp7, and I need to know the start event and end event during the pressing process, how I do it? thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688427/wp7-show-hide-application-bar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688427/wp7-show-hide-application-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The `ApplicationBar` API is quite restrictive, which is a deliberate move by Microsoft to ensure consistency. You cannot handle arbitrary events from the `ApplicationBar`. If you want this kind of behaviour, you will have to build your own UI to support it.

It is worth noting that your users will not expect 'long press' (more commonly referred to as tap-and-hold) behaviour on the app-bar.